# Grails giving me 404 on controller when submitting form

Tags: forms, grails

I have a basic controller, just like this:

```
class BookingController {

    def periodCheck(){

    }

    def periodInput(){

    }
```

Both `booking/periodCheck.gsp` and `booking/periodInput.gsp` have been created, and **they work** if I access typing the URL directly.

However, I have a form in `periodInput.gsp` that is supposed to send some data to `periodCheck`, and every time, when I send the form, I get a 404 error, saying that `The requested resource (/hoteledison/booking/periodCheck) is not available`. The form is defined like this:

```
<g:form action="periodCheck">
        <!-- here would go the fields -->
        <g:actionSubmit class="btn" value="Comprobar" />
</g:form>
```

What am I doing wrong? I've also tried defining `allowedMethods` in the controller, but that does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, according to [this blog post](http://www.augusttechgroup.com/tim/blog/2009/06/16/ohms-law-and-grails-form-submissions/), there's a difference between using `actionSubmit` and `submitButton`. For forms like mine, with just one action, I should have used the later.

Now it's working.